# How to execute aws glue scripts using python 2.7 from local machine?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

I have `aws cli` and `boto3` installed in my `python 2.7` environment. I want to do various operations like get schema information, get database details of all the tables present in AWS Glue console. I tried below samples of scripts:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
persons = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
             database="records",
             table_name="recordsrecords_converted_json")
print "Count: ", persons.count()
persons.printSchema()
```

I got error `ImportError: No module named awsglue.transforms` which should be correct as there is no such package present in boto3 as I identified using the command `dir(boto3)`. I found that `boto3` offers various client calls through `awscli` and we can access them by using `client=boto3.client('glue')`. So, for getting schema information as above, I tried below sample code:

```
import sys
import boto3
client=boto3.client('glue')
response = client.get_databases(
    CatalogId='string',
    NextToken='string',
    MaxResults=123
)
print client
```

But then I get this error:
`AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetDatabases operation: Cross account access is not allowed.`

I am pretty sure that either one of them or probably both of them are correct approaches to get what I am trying to get but something doesn't fall into correct slots here. Any ideas to get the details about the schema and database tables from AWS Glue using python 2.7 locally like I tried above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works for me, and am using locally setup Zeppelin notebook, as a dev end point.  The printschema reads the schema from the data catalog.

Hope you have enabled the ssh tunnelling as well.

```
%pyspark
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.transforms import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# Create a Glue context
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

# Create a DynamicFrame using the 'persons_json' table
medicare_dynamicframe = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="payments", table_name="medicaremedicare_hospital_provider_csv")

# Print out information about this data
print "Count:  ", medicare_dynamicframe.count()
medicare_dynamicframe.printSchema()
```

Also you may need to make some changes for Spark interpreter, (tick on the **Connect to existing process** option available in the top, and host(localhost), port number (9007).

**For second part** You need to to do `aws configure` and then create glue client after installing `boto3` client. After this, check your proxy settings for hiding behind a firewall or company network.

To be clear, `boto3` client is helpful for all AWS related client side api and for server side, Zeppelin way is the best.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help on setting up local Zeppelin notebook for development.

Comment: How do you get data from Glue Catalog locally?

Comment: thanks @YuvaKumar. I also figured out that `awsglue` imports works via Zeppelin using the primary `ssh` key login. So that fixes first part of the code fix. The second part of code was really a proxy issue from my side which were not configurable while trying to do `aws configure` which I later did and then the client side scripts worked. Let me edit your answer with that information as well and mark it as accepted. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @AlexeyBakulin: To get data from Glue catalog, check out the `boto3` documentation for available services for AWS Glue. They have many client side methods available there. For this example, I am getting my data by specifying my `S3` bucket path while creating crwaler in AWS Glue and also providing `db details` there. Hope this helps.